# Transparent Window

Tags: java, eclipse, swing, jframe, jpanel

I have a fullscreen `JFrame`. I added a map to `JPanel` then added it to `JFrame`. Now I want to add a transparent window to `JFrame`. I want to see all map and I want to move transparent window.

I did it with internal frame but I couldn't it's title tranparent.

Could you help me about this?

Thanks ...

Answer (score 2):

One possible way is to add a JPanel to the glasspane.

Answer (score 2):

http://techgearup.wordpress.com/2008/09/19/transparent-jframe-background/

This might help... as a starting point, at least.

Answer (score 2):

Does `com.sun.awt.AWTUtilities.setWi­ndowOpacity(this, 0.3f);` work? (although it's not an officially supported API, natch). Regardless, there's an article on this [here](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/GUI/translucent_shaped_windows/).

Answer (score 1):

If you´r having truble finding it on google it could be because you'll have to google "Translucent"

http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/GUI/translucent_shaped_windows/